# Plot data from dataframe to understand much better it - Pandas, matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using `pandas` with some data like the following,

```
    User Code   Group   Task Type   Time
0   u00         G00     1D          3.378195
1   u00         G00     1D          3.032764
2   u00         G00     1D          3.391991
3   u00         G00     2D          4.035652
4   u00         G00     2D          2.991456
5   u00         G00     2D          3.972600
6   u01         G01     2D          3.236271
7   u01         G01     2D          3.313933
8   u01         G01     2D          3.053321
9   u01         G01     1D          3.439581
10  u01         G01     1D          3.526108
11  u01         G01     1D          3.392685
...
```

What I'm doing now is grouping the data obtaining the average of the time for 2 task type like this,

```
mean_data = data.groupby(['User Code','Group','Task Type']).mean()
```

And I obtain a dataframe like this

```
                                Time
User Code   Group   Task Type   
u00         G00     1D          3.727686
                    2D          4.193184
u01         G01     1D          3.507185
                    2D          3.462133
u02         G01     1D          2.111048
                    2D          1.582493
...
```

Here I'm doubting if I'm doing correctly because I don't understand why `Time` appears in a row and the other fields i other row. But know I want to plot this results using `matplotlib` and observe the difference between groups and tasks, to understand if the times depends of the group or task. But I really don't know how to do it...

I know I'm not writing some try, but this is because I really don't know how to afront it. For example if I want to do a double barplot, that the x-axis is the user, the y-axis the time and one barplot is task 1D and the other task 2D, how I take this from the dataframe?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `groupby` operation works fine. The reason for `Time` being one row above the other labels is that the `groupby` has created a structure called a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). I suppose the output is formatted in this way to make it easier to distinguish the index columns from the data value columns.

For plotting this, I recommend using seaborn. Then you can pass your original data frame to the plotting function and specify by which variables to group in which way. [This part](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html#statistical-estimation-within-categories) of the official tutorial would be a good place to start.

Comment: I think the problem is this multindex, because now if I print `df.columns()` I just have one column, the time and I can't plot it...

Comment: @Lleims Yes, there's only one column left, because you used every variable except `Time` for the grouping. You could still plot the result, e.g. with a barplot, by using some combination of index values as the x variable, but as I mentioned the easiest way to do this is with seaborn, using the original data frame.